# Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir' when I type 'gulp' in my laravel project dir

Tags: gulp

Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir' when I type 'gulp' in my laravel project dir.

```
D:\phpStudy\WWW\Vuedo\vuedo>gulp
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\phpStudy\WWW\Vuedo\vuedo\gulpfile.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

D:\phpStudy\WWW\Vuedo\vuedo>
```

Answer (score 0):

After `npm install npm@latest -g` update, and `npm install` command exec in my project dir, the problem resolved.